# Unable to connect to Exchange server with ews-php

Tags: php, exchangewebservices

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, so please forgive me.

I have an account set up on Office365. The domain name "mail.mydomain.com" is an exchange server pointing to the Office365 setup.

I'm trying to use ews-php to connect to the server:
https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews

When I enter the domain, my username, and password to create an ExchangeWebServices object, it seems to connect.

But when I create a EWSType_FindItemType object, I get one of two messages:
`Uncaught SoapFault exception: [VersionMismatch] Wrong Version`
or
`Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document`

I've tried all four of the versions available in php-ews, with the same results.

Has anyone had a similar problem? Is there something simple I'm missing?

Thanks,
--Ian

Comment: The project is over 2 years old, are you sure it supports Office365? The dependencies state it only supports Exchange 2007 or 2010.

Comment: I wondered about that, but I'm unsure of two things - how can I tell what version the server is running (2007, 2010, 2010_SP1, etc). Also, I don't know of another PHP / EWS api. I'd rather not write my own SOAP calls... :)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the office365 product, sorry, you'd have to check around...

Comment: O365 is likely E2013 worldwide by now (certainly is in the US), however, it should be able to speak to an E2010 client, which is what the RequestedVersion is for in the ExchangeService object.  You can get the server version in the AD response, but again, it should not matter.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this PHP interface.

Comment: Hi, pjneary! What is the "AD response"? And is there another PHP / Exchange interface you know of?

Comment: Here's another PHP client: http://ewswrapper.lafiel.net/. It too is a bit stale.